# grep exact match in colon delimited string

Tags: grep, pattern-matching

I am trying to extract the version from a colon delimited list. The value I want is for ***foo***, however there is another value in the list called ***foo-bar*** causing both values to return. This is what I am doing:

```
LIST="foo:1.0.0
foo-bar:1.0.1"

VERSION=$(echo "${LIST}" | grep "\bfoo\b" | cut -s -d':' -f2)

echo -e "VERSION: ${VERSION}"
```

Output:

```
VERSION: 1.0.0
1.0.1
```

**NOTE:** Sometimes LIST will look like the following, which should result in version being empty (this is expected).

```
LIST="foo
foo-bar:1.0.1"
```

Comment: Try `grep -P "\bfoo\b(?!-)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a PCRE regex enabled with `-P` option and use a `(?!-)` negative lookahead that will fail the match in case there is a `-` after a whole word `foo`:

```
grep -P "\bfoo\b(?!-)"
```

See [online demo](http://ideone.com/8IAW2j)

Answer (score 0):

This regex should extract any number and optional dots at the end of each line. If the line ends with a colon, then it won't match.

```
grep -oE '(([[:digit:]]+[.]*)+)$
```